# How to install ngCookies in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi I am trying to install ngCookies in my ionic app .using `npm install angular-cookie` command then I am getting an error message like

```
> Administrators-MacBook-Pro:QShieldpro3may munavvar$ npm install angular-cookie npm WARN package.json qshieldpro@1.0.0 No repository
> field. npm WARN package.json qshieldpro@1.0.0 No README data npm ERR!
> 404 404 Not Found: angular-cookie npm ERR! 404  npm ERR! 404
> 'angular-cookie' is not in the npm registry. npm ERR! 404 You should
> bug the author to publish it npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a
> dependency of 'qshieldpro' npm ERR! 404  npm ERR! 404 Note that you
> can also install from a npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or
> git url.
> 
> npm ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0 npm ERR! command "node"
> "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "angular-cookie" npm ERR! cwd
> /Users/munavvar/QShieldpro3may npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33 npm ERR! npm
> -v 1.4.28 npm ERR! code E404 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in: npm ERR!    
> /Users/munavvar/QShieldpro3may/npm-debug.log npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed a S at the end of cookies :

https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies

Comment: Thanks, now i tried like that i got the                              Administrators-MacBook-Pro:QShieldpro3may munavvar$ npm install angular-cookies
npm WARN package.json qshieldpro@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json qshieldpro@1.0.0 No README data
angular-cookies@1.3.15 node_modules/angular-cookies
Administrators-MacBook-Pro:QShieldpro3may munavvar$

Comment: have you tried with bower : bower install angular-cookies

Comment: Just tried now get this message Administrators-MacBook-Pro:QShieldpro3may munavvar$ bower install angular-cookies
-bash: bower: command not found
Administrators-MacBook-Pro:QShieldpro3may munavvar$

Comment: install first bower : npm install -g bower then launch bower install angular-cookies

Comment: need to install ngcookies inside the app rite?